# Creating Azure dashboards for each environment

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-dashboard

I have an azure dashboard on DV resource group (application insights per environment - Dev, test, staging and prod).

I want to move that DV dashboard into other environments, what is the best way to do that?

I can see Download and Clone options, but, i am not sure, what are the steps to do that? Can i clone it and publish it to another environment directly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can download and upload to new dashboard and customized as per your wish. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards

Comment: Thanks, that will help, i can mark that as accepted answer(if you put it as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and upload to new dashboard and customized as per your wish.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards